# How to create a right triangle with asterisk without def function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far what I have is:

```
base = int(input("Enter a value"))
for row in range(base):
    for colomb in range(row+1):
        print('*', end='')
        print()
```

Comment: Looks like SO should have a `homework` tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there. You just need to unindent the last `print()`. Example -

```
for row in range(base):
    for colomb in range(row+1):
        print('*', end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharon's answer is the quickest solution to make the code you have work, but you could also do fewer runs through `for` loops by just printing (once) the entire string. `"a" * 3` is `"aaa"`, for instance, so you could do:

```
for row in range(1, base+1):  # now the range runs [1-base] instead of [0-base-1]
    print("*" * row)
```